# How to bump a UITableViewCell into the next section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with two sections. The first section can have a maximum number of n items in it. Right now When you drag and drop a cell from the second section into the first section when it already has n items, the moved cell will drop down into row 0 of the second section using:

```
(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

However, I'd like the moved row to stay at the proposed destination and the former nth item of the first section to be bumped down to row 0 of the second section instead. What's the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: your question is not clear...

Comment: @Rajesh When I drag a new item into the first section of a table view when it is "full" , I'd like that item to stay where it was put and the last item in that section to move down to the first row of the second section, so the number of items in the first section doesn't exceed the maximum number of items. Right now I'm putting the item being moved into the second section because the mentioned method works with the animations provided.